# AWK Script along with loop and if condition

Tags: shell, awk, grep

The input file is as below

```
827 819
830 826
828 752
756 694
828 728
821 701
724 708
826 842
719 713
764 783
752 828
694 756
```

`#$1` is my first row and $2 is my second row. I am trying to omit rows such as 11th row which is the same as the 3rd row but with swapped values. Basically, for every $1 $2 that also has $2 $1, I want to omit the latter. This is just a snippet of the data. There are many such values in the actual dataset.`

I have tried the below:

```
awk -F “ “ ‘{ for i in cat 686.edges.txt | if [ expr $1 $2 == expr $2 $1 ] then #Evaluating the condition from file
```

and

```
awk -F “ “ ‘{ print $2  $1 }’ >> t.txt else ‘{ print “ Not found “ } fi #Printing all the $y $x into a file
```

and

```
awk -F “ “ ‘{ for i in cat t.txt} | grep -v "$1 $2" 686.edges.txt >> new.txt
```

I am reading inputs from t.txt which is the result of the previous operation and removing all of them from the main file and writing it in new.txt

I am unable to execute as I have been getting errors. Can anybody evaluate the above and correct me.

Comment: Make sure in your actual script, you are using real quotes (`"` and `'`) and not the "smart" quotes (`“` and `‘`) that are in your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This prints all rows unless the reverse of the row has been previously seen:

```
$ awk '!seen[$2" "$1] {print} {seen[$0]=1}' t.txt
827 819
830 826
828 752
756 694
828 728
821 701
724 708
826 842
719 713
764 783
```

This assumes that the columns are separated by a space.  If they are separated by, for example, a tab, then a minor change to the code is needed.

To write the output to `new.txt` instead of the terminal, use:

```
awk '!seen[$2" "$1] {print} {seen[$0]=1}' t.txt >new.txt
```

#### How it works

`awk` reads in a record (row) at a time.  Each row is divided into fields (columns).  We use the array `seen` to keep track of which (reversed) rows have been previously seen.

- `!seen[$2" "$1] {print}`

  If the reverse of the current row has not been previously seen, then print the row.  (`!` is the awk symbol for "not".)
- `{seen[$0]=1}`

  Mark the current row as seen.

### Alternate: Omitting rows seen previously regardless of order

This will omit printing any row that had been previously seen either as is or in reverse order:

```
awk '0==seen[$0] {print} {seen[$0]=1; seen[$2" "$1]=1}' t.txt >new.txt
```

### Solution using multi-dimensional arrays

As suggested by Glenn Jackman, if your awk supports multi-dimensional arrays, then the above two solutions can be written:

```
awk --posix '!seen[$2,$1] {print} {seen[$1,$2]=1;}' t.txt >new.txt
```

and

```
awk '!seen[$1,$2] {print} {seen[$1,$2]=1; seen[$2,$1]=1}' t.txt >new.txt
```

shellter points out this notation was supported in the original *The AWK Programming Language* (pages 52-3).  On the other hand, [Grymoire](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html#uh-23) describes this notation as "invalid". So, it may not work on all versions of awk.  It is, however, supported by GNU awk (Linux).  Because this notation is required by [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/utilities/awk.html), it likely should work in all *modern* awks.

Comment: Not sure if it's a requirement or concern, but this will not prevent repeated lines in the same order... just reversed ones.

Comment: @MarkReed Yes, that was how I interpreted the OP's question.  However, your interpretation is also reasonable, so I just added a version that omits rows both types of repeats. For the sample dataset, it makes no difference.

Comment: The output obtained from the above instructions is :

Comment: @SujayShalawadi Please provide details.  Are you saying that the complete output from the command is a single colon, `:`?

Comment: use `seen[$1,$2]` instead. That uses a control character to join the strings: that character most likely is not in a text file. [reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Multidimensional.html#Multidimensional). Or specify the field separator explicitly and use `seen[$0]` and `seen[$2 FS $1]` to get the original line and the "reverse".

Comment: @glennjackman That is nice.  The GNU reference that you cite makes it seem general.  According to [Grymoire](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html#uh-23), however, that syntax is GNU-specific and I am always surprised by how many people here use BSD tools.

Comment: @glennjackman   I just added your suggested approach to the answer.

Comment: Using ',' in assoc array keys goes back to the original "The AWK Programming Language" ;-) P 52-3. "awk concatenates the components of the subscript ... Test for membership `if ((i,j) in arr) ...`, to loop over such an array, you must do `for (k in arr) ...` and use `split(k,x,SUBSEP)` to access individual subscripts components" (edited for brevity). Good luck to all.

Comment: @shellter Thanks for that info. I updated the answer again.  I also found the comma-notation mentioned in the POSIX docs.

Comment: @John1024 if Grymoire says that `seen[$1,$2]` is gawk-specific then (s)he is confused. What IS gawk-specific syntax is `seen[$1][$2]` as that represents a true 2D array.

Comment: @John1024: sorry about the previous comment. I lost connection. The output obtained for the sample out is 752 828 and 694 756. How can I negate this from my original data and get an output like what you have shown?

Comment: @John1024 Your solution worked out. I tried out on the entire data set. Thanks :)